# How many $k$-bit words of a random bitstring are we expected to extract before all $2^k$ possible words occur?

Tags: statistical-test, probability

Let $C(X)$ denote the cardinality of the set $X$. For example, $C(\{0\}) = 1, C(\{0, 2\}) = 2$ etc.

Let $S$ denote a (potentially infinite) sequence of random bits. Split $S$ into $k$-bit words $w_1, w_2, w_3, \ldots$ For example, if $k = 4$ and $S = 0001111010100100\ldots$, then $w_1 = 0001, w_2 = 1110, w_3 = 1010, \ldots$

At each step $i$ (here $i \geq 1$), do the following sub-steps:

1. Extract $w_i$ and go to sub-step 2;
2. If $C(X) < 2^k$ and $X$ contains $w_i$, do not do anything and go to step $(i+1)$; if $C(X) < 2^k$ and $X$ does not contain $w_i$, put $w_i$ in $X$ and go to sub-step 3;
3. If $C(X) < 2^k$, go to step $(i+1)$; if $C(X) = 2^k$, stop.

Question: what is the expected value of $i$ when the above algorithm halts? In other words, if $S$ is the source of truly random or unbiased pseudo-random bits, how many words should we expect to extract to fill $X$ with all possible $k$-bit elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This known as the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), with the number of coupons replaced by $2^k$ and $k$ is the number of independent bits drawn ($k=4$ in the question's example).

It's expected $(k\log(2)+\gamma)\,2^k+\frac12+\mathcal O(2^{-k})$ extractions, where $\gamma\approx0.5772$ is [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), and $\log(2)\approx0.6931$.

When few experiments are made, a rough approximation of the expectation is often good enough, e.g. $0.7\,k\,2^k$. The distribution has a [long tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail). I think the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is $\approx\frac\pi{\sqrt6}\,2^k\approx1.3\times 2^k$.